# Slow SELECT COUNT(*), information_schema, cardinality field

Tags: mysql, database-performance, large-data-volumes, large-data

I have a large (60+ millions of records) table. 
This table has a primary key (id, auto_increment, index id)

I have a report that selects records from this table. And to browse and navigate through this report (written in PHP) I'm using the pagination script.

This script using SELECT COUNT(*) to get the total amount of records in this table.
SELECT COUNT(*) is very slow.

**The question:**
Can i query cardinality field in statistics table, information_schema DB where table_name = my_large_table_name and column_name = id and(or) index_name is the index name of my auto_incremented id and then use the result as the total amount of rows in my pagination script?

**UPDATE:**

Or can i query the `TABLE_ROWS` field in table `TABLES` in `information_schema`, to get the total amount ow rows in my table? With the result be accurate?

The table using InnoDB engine.

Comment: If it's innodb - then it's an expected behaviour

Comment: It's innoDB. Could you please tell me what do you mean by expected behaviour?

Comment: it's expected that `COUNT(*)` works slowly in innodb

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an innodb table, where the row count is not cached and therefore must be computed.

The table stats are also not likely to be accurate:

> For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an
>   approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40 to
>   50%.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Have you seen `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: From docs: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()` can be useful in situations when you want to restrict the number of rows that a query returns, but also determine the number of rows in the full result set without running the query again.
This is not really what i need. Just tried to run this: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM phone_geo;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` and it's really fast...

Comment: WHat about `TABLE_ROWS` field in table `TABLES` in `information_schema` DB?

Comment: If you're paginating, you're probably using `LIMIT` to get X records back per page.  Knowing `FOUND_ROWS` will tell you how many pages to allow for.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is a type, i meant to say it's not fast (at all) there is almost no difference from `SELECT COUNT()`

Comment: Again, if you're paginating, you should be selecting 10-20 rows at a time, using `LIMIT`, right?  If so, that should be fast (or you've got other problems).  Add the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to that first query and then `SELECT FOUND_ROWS` to find out how many rows the original query would have returned without the limit.  You should not be querying the whole table.